# JS inserting objects correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, include

I am trying to make miny pocket pokemon game. Here is how I am storing the pokemon.

```
let Charmander = {
        "name": "Charmander",
        "type": "fire",
        "hp": "70",
        "weaknesses": ["ground", "rock", "water"],
    };
let Bulbasaur = {
        "name": "Bulbasaur",
        "type": ["Grass", "Poison"],
        "hp": "70",
        "weaknesses": ["Fire", "Flying", "Ice", "Psychic"],
    };
let Squirtle = {
        "name": "Squirtle",
        "type": "Water",
        "hp": "60",
        "weaknesses": ["Electric", "Grass"],
};
```

It then asks you to pick which starting pokemon you want.

```
let startingChoice = prompt("What is your starting Pokemon " + Charmander.name + ", " + Bulbasaur.name + ", " + Squirtle.name);
```

I then create an array for the first pokemon that can be picked

```
let firstPokemon = [ Charmander.name, Bulbasaur.name, Squirtle.name];
```

I thennnn check the result of what you have typed in to see if it is in there by doing this.

```
if(startingChoice == "Charmander"){

    pokeBox.push(Charmander);

} else if(startingChoice == "Bulbasaur"){
    pokeBox.push(Bulbasaur);
}else{
    pokeBox.push(Squirtle);
}



}else{
    console.log("Chupa");
}
```

As you can see above that is pretty inefficient. How can I make it so that when it gets put into your pokeBox it adds in all of the objects info without the need of all of the info statements.

This is the result of pokeBox
`Object { name: "Charmander", type: "fire", hp: "70", … }`
How can I make this more efficient?

Comment: Use a single object , instead of many individual objects, that use the names as keys and the info objects as values. Then just use the name entered as the key to get the info object, eg `pokemons[promptedName]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you declare pokeBox by chance?

```
    let starterKantoPokemon = [{
        "name": "Charmander",
        "type": "fire",
        "hp": "70",
        "weaknesses": ["ground", "rock", "water"],
    },
    {
        "name": "Bulbasaur",
        "type": ["Grass", "Poison"],
        "hp": "70",
        "weaknesses": ["Fire", "Flying", "Ice", "Psychic"],
    },
    {
        "name": "Squirtle",
        "type": "Water",
        "hp": "60",
        "weaknesses": ["Electric", "Grass"],
  }];
    let pokeBox = []; 

    let hasPokemonBeenChosen = false;
    while(!hasPokemonBeenChosen)
    {
        let startingChoice = prompt("What is your starting Pokemon\n 1. " + starterKantoPokemon[0].name + ", 2." + starterKantoPokemon[1].name + ", 3." + starterKantoPokemon[2].name);
       if(startingChoice >= 1 && startingChoice <=3) {
         pokeBox.push(starterKantoPokemon[startingChoice - 1]);
         hasPokemonBeenChosen = true;
       } 
}
console.log('Professor Oak: Hmm...' + pokeBox[0].name + '. Good choice!');
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to put all the pokemon in their own object. Then you can code it in such a way where all that matters is the pokemon in the object, no repeating names or anything. In the example below, you could add or remove any pokemon you like and it'll work the same way.

```js
const
  pokemon = {
       charmander: {
          "name": "Charmander",
          "type": "fire",
          "hp": "70",
          "weaknesses": ["ground", "rock", "water"],
      },
      bulbasaur: {
          "name": "Bulbasaur",
          "type": ["Grass", "Poison"],
          "hp": "70",
          "weaknesses": ["Fire", "Flying", "Ice", "Psychic"],
      },
      squirtle: {
          "name": "Squirtle",
          "type": "Water",
          "hp": "60",
          "weaknesses": ["Electric", "Grass"],
      },
  },
  pokeBox = [],
  promptString = `What is your starting pokemon?\n` +
    Object.values(pokemon)
    .map(p => p.name)
    .join(`, `),
  choice = prompt(promptString);
    
const lowerCaseChoice = choice.toLowerCase();
if (lowerCaseChoice in pokemon)
    pokeBox.push(pokemon[lowerCaseChoice]);
else
    console.log(`that is not a valid option`);

console.log(pokeBox)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
    let pokeList = [{
        "name": "Charmander",
        "type": "fire",
        "hp": "70",
        "weaknesses": ["ground", "rock", "water"],
    }, {
        "name": "Bulbasaur",
        "type": ["Grass", "Poison"],
        "hp": "70",
        "weaknesses": ["Fire", "Flying", "Ice", "Psychic"],
    }, {
        "name": "Squirtle",
        "type": "Water",
        "hp": "60",
        "weaknesses": ["Electric", "Grass"],
}]
var name = "";
var pokeName = pokeList.filter((p)=>{
    name += p.name+", ";
})
let startingChoice = prompt("What is your starting Pokemon " + name.slice(0, -2));

var pokeBox = [];

pokeList.forEach(function(item, index){
    if(startingChoice == item.name){
        pokeBox.push(item)
    }
})

console.log(pokeBox)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Hope this works for you, This is one of the efficient ways.

```js
let starterPokemons = {
       charmander: {
          "name": "Charmander",
          "type": "fire",
          "hp": "70",
          "weaknesses": ["ground", "rock", "water"],
      },
      bulbasaur: {
          "name": "Bulbasaur",
          "type": ["Grass", "Poison"],
          "hp": "70",
          "weaknesses": ["Fire", "Flying", "Ice", "Psychic"],
      },
      squirtle: {
          "name": "Squirtle",
          "type": "Water",
          "hp": "60",
          "weaknesses": ["Electric", "Grass"],
      },
  };
let pokeBox = [];
let promptQuestion = 'What is your starting Pokemon\n';
Object.keys(starterPokemons).forEach(function(pokemon){
    promptQuestion += pokemon + ', ';
});

while(pokeBox.length == 0)
{
    let startingChoice = prompt(promptQuestion.slice(0, -2));
    startingChoice = startingChoice.toLowerCase();

    if(starterPokemons[startingChoice] == undefined){
        alert("Invalid Starter Pokemon");
    }
    else{
        pokeBox.push(starterPokemons[startingChoice]);
        alert("Congratulations you have selected " + starterPokemons[startingChoice].name + " as your Starter Pokemon");
    }
}
```